# Detecting face very fast from video using vision.CascadeObjectDetector in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, computer-vision, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I wrote matlab code for face detection.In my code it is detecting face for first 100 frames and it crop  faces from each frame and saves it in database folder.Problems iam facing

1.Detecting frame by frame is very slow.Is there any idea to run  faster since i have to work on 4000 frames.

2.In my database folder it has to show 1 to 100 face images but it is not showing 11th and 12th face images directly it showing 13th face image after 10th image.23rd face image is blurr.Likewise so many images are missing and some are blurr.Last image number it is showing as 216.But total 106 face images are there in database folder.In that 12 images are  blurr.Remaining are correct images.

```
clc;
clear all;

obj=vision.VideoFileReader('basu.avi');

for k=0:99

videoFrame      = step(obj);
%using viola-jones algorithm
      FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;

     %FaceDetect
      BB = step(FaceDetect,videoFrame);
      %BB
       figure(2),imshow(videoFrame);

for i = 1:size(BB,1)
      rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',3,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','r');
end

%crop faces and convert it to gray
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
J= imcrop(videoFrame,BB(i,:));
I=rgb2gray(imresize(J,[292,376]));

%save cropped faces in database folder
filename = ['G:\matlab_installed\bin\database\' num2str(i+k*(size(BB,1))) '.jpg'];
    imwrite(I,filename);
end
end
```

Comment: Try moving the `FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;` outside the loop, it might speed up things a bit.

Comment: For loop is to run for number of frames.How it can be done outside the loop.Video means its collection of frames.

Comment: Of course it is. You misunderstood my suggestion, please read it again. I suggested you to move only **one line** outside the loop, to avoid creating a face detection object everytime (you only need to create it once and, then, you can use it for each frame).

Comment: Can you use the integrated profiler to see which lines take how much time? Use the button "Run and Time" and post the results.

Comment: Elapsed time is 130.401650 seconds.I used tic()and toc() for whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of things you can try:

- Definitely move `FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;` outside of the loop. You only need to create the face detector object once. Re-creating it for every frame is definitely your performance bottleneck.
- `vision.VideoFileReader` returns a frame of class `'single'` by default. If you change the output data type to `'uint8'`, that should speed up the face detector.  Use `obj=vision.VideoFileReader('basu.avi', 'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8');`
- `vision.VideoFileReader` can also do the conversion to grayscale for you. Use `obj=vision.VideoFileReader('basu.avi', 'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8', 'ImageColorSpace', 'Intensity');`  This may be faster than calling `rgb2gray`.
- Try limiting the size of the faces being detected using `'MinSize'` and `'MaxSize'` options of `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` and/or try downsampling the frame before detecting faces.

Comment: dima do you know how to set fixed size for vision.CascadeObjectDetector? (with or without calling 'MinSize' / 'MaxSize')

Comment: like a static size that you define once for vision.CascadeObjectDetector so the bbox just snapshots this fixed size?